# regex match starts and ends with expression using angular

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, angular7

I have my working example here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fk2vpr?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

here I wrote condition like if word starts and ends with { and } they need to highlight and in editable way. here its working fine for word which is having no space like {username} but in case of {  host} then its not taking that word to highlight and also if somewords like {pas}!!

then word of {pas} alone needs to highlight but its taking along with that !!

Can anyone assist me what mistake I made on this scenario

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code it will work.

```
 const editable = data.match(/{+.*?}+/gi);
  if(editable){
    editable.map(word => {
      const re= new RegExp(word,'g');
      data = data.replace(re,' '+ word.replace(/\s/gi,'')+' ')
    })
  }
```

[image]

As per above code the token {username}!! will not work as we are splitting with space. To resolve that problem we can do add extra space before and after of that token. Use below line to work in all condition.

```
data = data.replace(word, ' ' + word.replace(/\s/g,'') + ' ')
```

Comment: is it possible to add another condition in match like { and } (or) {{ }} because even words with {{}} is showing as {

Comment: and one more issue, replacement is taking for first occurence alone its not taking for next occurence. reference https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fk2vpr?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: use this regex /{+.*?}+/gi in the match method. g is for return all the matches not only the first one. 
Could you share the stackblitz for the first issue as its not clear to me.

Comment: In my previous comment I have shared working stackblitz with my issue can you check that

Comment: In the previous comment stackblitz it is taking first occurrence only which solves with the regex with /gi options. Is there any other issue?

Comment: Its all absolutely working thanks alot for your help

Comment: one small thing , {{}} cases are replaced with { its because we have only one condition for { can we change that case too?

Comment: and I found one more case {{user-name}} then its taking as { user name } and its not been highlight., https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fk2vpr?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts here i have all type values to find issue

Comment: Can multiple words with space be there inside { } ?
As we are splitting with space we are replacing every space with empty string inside { } bcoz if we put space inside braces then splitting should be the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204038/discussion-between-kavya-shree-and-pujan-shah).

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tstlx6 if you check this url, if sameword repeats then condition not working for second occurence . can you check in this issue?

Comment: Just want to know both the cases {}, {{}} are allowed or any one case only required

Comment: only {} this case required

Comment: if you check my working url, there is 2 problem one is with view.map.{user-name} view.map.{user-name} when same word repeats and another one its adding spaces before {user-name} so its showing view.map. {user-name} so when i download content its not taking view.map.user-name instead added spaces

Comment: If only {} case is required then try with this code

      editable.map(word => {
        const re = new RegExp(word,'g');
        data = data.replace(re, ' ' + word.replace(/\s/gi,'') + ' ')
      })

Comment: I tried like this . If I remove space then again old issue coming like view.map.username is taken as one word. Now just need to remove space in case of word after . Other than that it's perfectly fine

Comment: Sorry pasted wrong code. We don't need to remove space. Updated the main answer. plz check it.

Comment: still im having that space in view.map. {username}., ie in case of word after comes with . tried with change https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tstlx6

Comment: Yes that space is needed otherwise how we can split the words with editable and non editable. To differentiate those words we are putting a space before and after {}

Comment: yeah that I can understand ., but in some place words are like this which means with . its like single word and like command so o/p shouldn't have that space., is it possible>

Comment: I mean only the word reach this position like view.map.{username} that space should not add its like view.map.[box] ,

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with mapping the `data.split(' ')`. Notice that when you call that on a string `username  {    username}  scrypt  secret  {password}` you will not get an array with 5 elements, as you would like (i.e `['username', '{    username}', 'scrypt', 'secret', '{password}']`), but it will split on **every** space character; so the resulting array looks more like this:

```
[
  'username',   '',
  '{',          '',
  '',           'username}',
  'scrypt',     'secret',
  '{password}'
]
```

If you can, I would advice on making the `arr` array as an array of arrays, each subarray consisting of words you want to launch a regex through. If this is, however, not an option, I would suggest not splitting like that, but mapping like this:

```js
this.mappedArr = this.arr.map(data => {
    const editable = data.match('([{].*?[}])');
    console.log(editable);
    return {
      editable,
      data: !editable ? 
            data :
            data.match(/(\{+ *)?\w+( *\}+)?/g).map(word => ({word, editable: word.match('^[{].*?[}]$')})) <
    };
})
```

This begs for refactoring though, but it should work as an emergency fix.

Comment: Hi david I have tried like this, may i know how can i add another condition for match like { or {{ as well., and in some case if particular element is having multiple words this condition {{ kavya babu }} not applied for few words . which means space between {} then its not considered.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fk2vpr?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Ugh, yes, now I noticed that this method is flawed. I've updated the regex in my answer to take into account many brackets (one after another). Multiple words is, while probably possible, above my abilities. Sorry, I'm no regex expert. Without prior input validation this is a herculean task in my opinion. Check Pujan's answer below, I think it may be more promising.